# Why variable isn’t working in select query?

Tags: c#, variables, dataadapter

Why this is working when I use absolute value but when i try to use variable as query parameter the query returns no data ?

```
private void SetBomNumber()
{
   
    try
    {
        da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Products.[ProductCode], Max(ISNULL([BomNumber], 0) + 1) AS NewBomSerial FROM Products LEFT JOIN Bom ON Products.ProductCode = Bom.ProductCode GROUP BY Products.[ProductCode] HAVING(((Products.[ProductCode]) = '210002')) ", Cn);
        da2.Fill(dt2);
        if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            int BomNumber= Convert.ToInt32(dt2.Rows[0]["NewBomSerial"].ToString());
            txtBomNum.Text = BomNumber.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("The Next Serial Is :" + BomNumber);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Query Doesn’t Work");
        }
        
    }
    catch (Exception Err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This Error Occured :" + Err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);


    }

}
```

With variable this shows the error message "The Query Doesn't work" ?

```
private void SetBomNumber()

{


try
{

    da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Products.[ProductCode], Max(ISNULL([BomNumber], 0) + 1) AS NewBomSerial FROM Products LEFT JOIN Bom ON Products.ProductCode = Bom.ProductCode GROUP BY Products.[ProductCode] HAVING(((Products.[ProductCode]) = @prcode)) ", Cn);
    da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prcode", "%" + txtprcode.Text + "%");
    da2.Fill(dt2);
    if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        int BomNumber= Convert.ToInt32(dt2.Rows[0]["NewBomSerial"].ToString());
        txtBomNum.Text = BomNumber.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show("The Next Serial Is :" + BomNumber);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Query Doesn’t Work");
    }
    
}
catch (Exception Err)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This Error Occured :" + Err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

This code works in other form with no problem , Thanks in Advance.

Comment: why are you wrapping the value with '%' characters?

Comment: That's the way it works in other forms. Is it wrong?

Comment: looks wrong to me, take them out and see what happens

Comment: Agreed with "%" wild-cards.  You are looking for an absolute value via equality, so it was looking for exactly % + value + % and thus no records.  The LIKE command works with wildcards for matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @DRapp comments thanks to him this worked for me :
If you need the condition to be the exact value of the variable then use :

```
da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Products.[ProductCode], Max(ISNULL([BomNumber], 0) + 1) AS NewBomSerial FROM Products LEFT JOIN Bom ON Products.ProductCode = Bom.ProductCode GROUP BY Products.[ProductCode] HAVING(((Products.[ProductCode]) = @prcode)) ", Cn);
           
da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prcode",  txtprcode.Text );
```

If you need the condition to be Like the variable you can use :

```
   da2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Products.[ProductCode], Max(ISNULL([BomNumber], 0) + 1) AS NewBomSerial FROM Products LEFT JOIN Bom ON Products.ProductCode = Bom.ProductCode GROUP BY Products.[ProductCode] HAVING(((Products.[ProductCode]) LIKE @prcode)) ", Cn);
               
   da2.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prcode", "%" +txtprcode.Text+ "%");
```

Thanks

Comment: good of u to take the trouble to make it an answer, mark is answered after 2 days, by selecting your answer as the answer [faq]

Comment: I will ,Thanks for your reply.